# Problem loading a tab-separated file using RStudio

Tags: r, csv, readr

Im trying to upload a dataset from .txt (tab separated file), but RStudio just do not recognize the contents.

Im wondering if it's about special encoding or something like that.

What I'm trying to upload:

[image]

What RSTUDIO shows:

[image]

```
library(readr)
X01172_BD03B_201902 <- read_delim("smp-22-09/01172_BD03B_201902.txt", 
    "\t", escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
View(X01172_BD03B_201902)
```

We are using readr library.

An screenshot with console error desc:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `read.csv()`:

```
X01172_BD03B_201902 <- read.csv("smp-22-09/01172_BD03B_201902.txt", sep = "\t")
```

Comment: Throw the following error:  "Error in make.names(col.names, unique = TRUE) : 
  invalid multibyte string at '<ff><fe>C'"

Comment: @DiegoPacheco Save the file as UTF-8 encoding and try again. `<ff><fe>` identify the UTF-16 encoding. R can't work with UTF-16

Comment: I've converted the file using excel/save as, but how can I automate this task? I have more than one hundred files with this little issue.

Comment: @DiegoPacheco I don't think it's possible with R since R can't read UTF-16. You have to use another language to convert the files first. C++ can do that: use `WideCharToMultiByte()` function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/stringapiset/nf-stringapiset-widechartomultibyte